# Create a custom template page in shopware5

Tags: shopware

I am working on my first shopware project. I need to create a new contact us page on shopware using my own template. My contact us page contains two forms and some other contents.

If someone can tell me how to create a custom template page on shopware I know how to add two forms and the other page contents into it.

In theme folder, there is a folder called “custom” for the content pages such as “about us” . I need to create a same type of page for my new contact us page.

Please let me know if the question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom Theme via the Theme Manager in the Backend, the CLI or on your own with a Folder below themes/Frontend/ThemeNameHere and a file "Theme.php"([documentation](https://developers.shopware.com/designers-guide/theme-startup-guide/#theme.php)).

After that you have to create a file at the same place where the one you want to override. In your case below themes/Frontend/ThemeNameHere/frontend/forms.

Then simply name the file like the original file and put in the first line `{extends file="parent:frontend/forms/fileNameHere"}` and copy the smallest available `{block name="specificBlockName"}{/block}`. After that you only have to change the selected theme in the backend to your new theme.

I think this is very well explained in the [documentation](https://developers.shopware.com/designers-guide/getting-started/).

Additional you can take a look at [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/shopware-template-training-basic/) but it is in german.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @all is the answer better now? I recognized that a simple link as answer whether it helps or not isn't the best idea.